# regex for comma separated value of multiple of 100 and upto 1000

Tags: regex

Can any body help me out for one regular expression ,which validate comma separated values of multiple of 100 and upto 1000 only.

For example `100,200,1000`
for example `100,1000,100`

Regards,
PK

Answer (score 4):

Have a try with this one:

```
^(?:10|[1-9])00(?:,\s*(?:10|[1-9])00)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?:10|[1-9])00(?:,\s*(?:10|[1-9])00)*$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    10                       '10'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  00                       '00'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      10                       '10'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    00                       '00'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You might want to add some anchors too, and maybe optional spaces.

Comment: @user3134939: No, it doesn't. It accept only numbers between 100 and 1000.

Comment: @M42 but i want to limit up to 1000 and mutiple of 100 within comma separation

Comment: @user3134939: It works as wanted, it matches the numbers multiple of 100 from 100 to 1000 included. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:1000,?|[1-9]00,?)+$
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/aH3cQ2)**